# Project Sync failed| Downloading gradle failed|Connection reset error

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-things

Error log:-

```
2018-12-10 16:30:43,373 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - About to execute Gradle tasks: [assemble]

2018-12-10 16:30:43,373 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: BUILD_EXECUTOR_CREATED

2018-12-10 16:30:43,607 [ thread 29]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre

2018-12-10 16:30:43,622 [ thread 29]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Build command line options: [-Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true]

2018-12-10 16:30:43,794 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: BUILD_STARTED

2018-12-10 16:30:43,794 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Starting batch update for project: Project 'C:\Users\Mr.Bing\ApkProjects\Calculator' Calculator

2018-12-10 16:30:47,466 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender deactivation event: BUILD_FINISHED

2018-12-10 16:30:47,466 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Finishing batch update for project: Project 'C:\Users\Mr.Bing\ApkProjects\Calculator' Calculator

2018-12-10 16:30:47,529 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in3 s 861 ms

2018-12-10 16:30:47,748 [ thread 31]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0.110 s.

2018-12-10 16:30:47,748 [ thread 31]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols in FAST mode, 0 source files from total 0 project files

2018-12-10 16:30:47,763 [ thread 31]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0.015 s.

2018-12-10 16:30:47,763 [ thread 31]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Header Maps finished in 0.000 s.

2018-12-10 16:30:48,045 [ thread 31]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Module Maps finished in 0.282 s.

2018-12-10 16:30:48,123 [ thread 31]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving Module Maps finished in 0.046 s.

2018-12-10 16:30:48,123 [ thread 31]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loaded 0 tables for 0 files (0 project files)

2018-12-10 16:30:48,138 [ thread 31]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 source files

2018-12-10 16:30:48,170 [ thread 31]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 unused headers

2018-12-10 16:30:48,170 [ thread 31]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0.032 s.

2018-12-10 16:30:48,185 [ thread 31]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving modified symbols for 0 files (0 tables of total 0)

2018-12-10 16:30:48,185 [ thread 31]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0.000 s.

2018-12-10 16:31:04,811 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - ide.actions.ShowFilePathAction -

Exit code 1
```

I dont know what the issue is about so cannot solve it too
I am a newbie to android studio and stack overflow as well.

Tried to provide local gradle but that failed too!

Build starts normally but then fails and shows Downloading gradle but then throws error showing: Connection reset

Comment: I fixed formatting, but your question is still missing useful information allowing expert to answer it.

Comment: I have edited it with new information

Answer (score 0):

add to project

build.gradle(Project:yourNameProject):

```
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

if not Check your gradle and plugin version:
[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle)

Comment: This doesnt seem to help with my issue